# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Connection has been administratively disabled by console/admin command. Try later

Tags: oracle, weblogic, connection-pooling

When our application tries to connect Oracle database, this exception is thrown:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Connection has been administratively disabled by console/admin command. Try later. java.lang.Exception: It was disabled at Tue Oct 20 23:55:14 CEST 2015
```

But, from Weblogic console the connection test returns OK.
[image]

Weblogic version: 12.1.3.0.0

Any explanation is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason the test works is because that is creating a connection and running a test query. That is not what your code is doing when it is using the data source in an ejb. The code is going through the connection pool and that is what has been marked as bad. There is no solution provided by Oracle that I have found except to: restart the server and that will re-enable the connection pool.

I suspect you have "Test connections on reserve" set because that is when this usually arises. What Weblogic does is: before it returns a connection from the pool it will run a test query, if the test query fails it waits and runs it one more time. If the query fails again it marks the connection as unhealthy. If all the connections in the pool become unhealthy it will mark the pool as disabled and gives you the error message you see: 'Connection has been administratively disabled by console/admin command. Try later.'

In regards to the 'Try Later' part of the error message, as far as I can tell Oracle is wrong about trying again later. I have never seen it recover later.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share this article that help me out to understand better my problem:

https://www.techpaste.com/2012/09/connection-administratively-destroyed-reconnect-oracle-weblogic-server/

```
The “java.sql.SQLException: Connection has been administratively destroyed.” is expected:
the DB was shutdown; even if it was restarted later, the JDBC connection are pointing to DB processes
that have been destroyed.

You need to restart your WebLogic Server to recreate new JDBC connections.
All the current transactions are lost, as the database was shutdown.

High availability of your RDBMS is required to minimize this issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other error before that one ?
Maybe in the log you can find that connection is been closed.

You can avoid this by selecting "Test on Connection Reserve" in the datasource.

Comment: Nope. Every time we want to execute query, this exception is thrown. It seems like Weblogic stores "dead" connections in pool, but for connection tests, uses recent connection.